# Gaps setting font-size in inline elements

Tags: html, css

I have problems setting font-size styles in inline elements. Some gaps comes up.
There are questions related to this issue but I've not found a solution to my case.

Given this code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <style>
        .container {
            font-size: 40px;
        }

        p {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .small {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <p>Big text</p>
            <p>
                <span class="small">
                    Small text
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span class="small">
                    Small text
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How could I remove the extra vertical gaps if **the HTML markup can't be modified and new CSS can only be applied to the container `div` and its children**?

I've tried setting `vertical-aling:top` and `line-height:0` but I can't get it to work.

What I need is this:

[image]

What I'm getting is:

[image]

Comment: Its working fine for me. I dont see any gaps

Comment: I'm using Chrome 59.0.3071.115

Comment: same version. Please update the question with the image of your current output

Comment: I have added a picture taken from the code snippet

Comment: If `<!doctype html>` is used it doesn't work. With `<!doctype>` or without a `doctype` it works out of the SO snippet as it adds the first doctype automatically. But I need to use `doctype html`

Comment: so, you even can't modify the HTML with javascript?

Comment: I can't because the code is just the minimal to reproduce the problem. Really it is a WYSIWG editor which generates the HTML. I'd prefer not to use JS.

Comment: You just now said _span must keep being inline elements_. Since there is only one element inside the `p`, the `span`, it won't matter if it is inline or not, or else you forgot to say why...so bottom line, there is too many _I can't do this_ and _I can't do that_. If you want a proper answer we need to know the full scope of the issue, or else we simply waist our time.

Comment: I did, it is a WYSIWG text editor which creates the markup so there can be multiple spans depending what the user writes and which styles he wants to apply. Showing minimal code to reproduce a problem is not always perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font-size on the `p` elements is still `40px`, the `small` class attributes are only being applied to the spans.  If the order of these elements is static, then you could just apply the font-size of 16px to all `p` and the font-size of 40px to just the first `p`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <style>
        .container {
            font-size: 40px;
        }

        p {
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        
        p:first-child {
            font-size: 40px;
        }

        .small {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <p>Big text</p>
            <p>
                <span>
                    Small text
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span class="small">
                    Small text
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: he clearly said, that he can't modify the HTML-output

Comment: nice... but what if the <p>Big text</p> is not always on the first position, or even worse, what if its output multiple times :P

Comment: yep, as I noted in my answer, it will only work if it is

Comment: but I concede that your answer is better in general ;)

Comment: I was lucky that it worked even if I wasn't actually sure what I was fiddling around :D :D

Comment: I ended up tweaking the editor to set the `line-height` and `font-size` of each `p` when necessary so this is the answer that better fits my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! Just add `.small {display: block}` to your CSS and you're save.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <style>
        .container {
            font-size: 40px;
        }

        p {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .small {
            font-size: 16px;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <p>Big text</p>
            <p>
                <span class="small">
                    Small text
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span class="small">
                    Small text
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y7edz1tj/

Comment: Thanks, but the spans must keep being inline elements. I'll upvote it because it is useful to know that.

Comment: Then you should consider using metame's answer... you really don't have much options here. there's a :has() css selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has but isn't supported by the browsers yet.